# Java - Google App Engine - InvalidClassException when I change a class that was stored in session scope

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I updated my User class, and now whenever someone that had the old version of the User class stored in their session scope accesses my site, I get an `InvalidClassException`.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.io.InvalidClassException: User; local class incompatible: 
stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4949038118012519093, 
local class serialVersionUID = -971500502189813151
```

How do I stop this error from happening for those users?  I could probably invalidate everyone's sessions every time I want to update a class that gets stored in session scope, but is there a better way, so that my user's don't have to login again?

Comment: I didn't close my browser, but I deleted all the sessions through the GAE datastore viewer, but still get the deserialization error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
private final long serialVersionUID=4949038118012519093;
```

to your class definition. New class should have the same serializable fields in the same order of course.

Comment: In Java when a class gets serialized and deserialized a check is done against the serialVersionUID for the class. The default behaviour is to assign a new random number to each serializable class when you compile, if one is not created by the developer. If you set one to a random number or -1 then as long as the class does not change you will be OK.

Comment: What happens if you add a generated serialVersionUID (for example in eclipse IDE) but then you modify the class and deploy the code without regenerating the serialVersionUID?